# Как вывести из таблицы записи, сгруппировав их по дате?

Tags: php, mysql

Прошу помощи. Догадываюсь, что вопрос элементарный, но моих мозгов не хватает. Интернет уже добросовестно прошерстил.

Дано: 2 таблицы. Из одной подтягиваются данные userId, status, diary (записи пользователей), end (это дата внесения записи в таблицу, хранится в DateTime) и lessonNum.

Из второй по lessonNum и userId подтягиваются картинки. Выборка формируется без проблем, подтягиваются все нужные записи.

До этого момента всё ок.

Получается 5 записей. 3 из них приходятся на 1 дату, ещё 2 на вторую. Задача в том, чтобы выводимые результаты группировались по датам. То есть для 1 даты выводятся 3 поста в блоке, и для второй даты тоже самое.

Вот мой код:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(end,'%d.%m.%Y') as end, wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4_access.* 
FROM wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4_access
INNER JOIN wp_uls_gallery_base3dsmax4
ON wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4_access.userId = wp_uls_gallery_base3dsmax4.userId
WHERE wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4_access.status = 3
AND wp_lessons_uls_base3dsmax4_access.lessonNum = wp_uls_gallery_base3dsmax4.lessonNum
GROUP BY end
ORDER BY end DESC
```

Проблема в том, что сейчас выводится либо 5 записей отдельно (по DateTime).  Либо, если заменить `GROUP BY end` на  `GROUP BY DATE(end)`, выводится 2 записи.

В общем, впёрся в то, как вывести результаты, сгруппировав их по дате. Конечно, можно извратиться на PHP, но хотелось бы запрос правильно построить.

Заранее, благодарю.

Comment: Та группировка, о которой Вы говорите, никакого отношения к SQL не имеет. Это уже проблема клиента, получившего результат и отображающего его на экране - определить, что в очередной записи другая дата, и начать новый блок. А запрос и без того правильный. Если не считать того, что `end` - зарезервированное слово, и его следует обрамить бэктиками.

Comment: Если у вас есть 5 записей, и вам все эти 5 записей нужны, то группировка в БД вам не нужна, она не сделает вам вложенные массивы, список строк возвращаемый БД всегда линейный, там нет  никаких вложенностей, которые вы очевидно хотите.
Если для работы с БД вы используете PDO, то там можно автоматически результат сгруппировать по первому полю, иначе руками.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Про end да, сейчас уже знаю. Таблицу создавал давным давно уже, когда понятия не имел про зарезервированные имена. С группировкой теперь понятнее стало. Хотя над тем, как разбить записи в блоках по датам, до сих пор туплю.